# Filtering a variable in bash script using regex tr or awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, regex-negation

`row1=$('+00 00:30:07.880000')`

`rowX=$('row1 | tr -dc '0-9')`

I basically want to filter out all the special characters and space.

I wish to have a output as follows.

`echo $'row1' = 003007.880000`

Comment: `echo '+00 00:30:07.880000' | tr -dc '0-9.'`

Comment: Or `echo '+00 00:30:07.880000' | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way to do that :

```
$ echo '+00 00:30:07.880000' | tr -dc '[0-9].'
00003007880000
```

Regards!

Comment: OP wants to keep the periods too.

Comment: I think OP struggled with bash syntax for both variable assignment and command substitution as well, so I'd suggest to show how to use them correctly as well

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions or external commands like `tr` for this.  Bash's built-in parameter expansion can do it:

```
row1='+00 00:30:07.880000'
row1=${row1//[^0-9.]/}
echo "row1=$row1"
```

outputs `row1=00003007.880000`.

The output has two leading zeros that are not in the output suggested in the question.  Maybe there's an unstated requirement to remove prefixes delimited by spaces.  If that is the case, possible code is:

```
row1='+00 00:30:07.880000'
row1=${row1##* }
row1=${row1//[^0-9.]/}
echo "row1=$row1"
```

That outputs `row1=003007.880000`.

See [How do I do string manipulations in bash?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for explanations of `${row1//[^0-9.]/}` and `${row1##* }`.